# Dapr pub/sub empty subscriber payload

Tags: dapr

My subscriber is being triggered when I publish a message but the data payload seems to be empty. I'm following the steps in the [pub/sub subscription methods](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/subscription-methods/#programmatic-subscriptions) documentation.

This is the app endpoint code:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(cors())

app.get('/dapr/subscribe', (_req, res) => {
  res.json([
    {
      pubsubname: "order-pub-sub",
      topic: "orders",
      route: "api/deliveries",
    }
  ]);
});

app.post('/api/deliveries', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const rawBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  console.log(`Data received: ${rawBody}`)
  res.status(200).send({ status: "SUCCESS" });
});
```

Starting the app:

```bash
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 --name dtc-rabbitmq rabbitmq

dapr run --app-id delivery --app-port 3100 --app-protocol http --dapr-http-port 3501 --components-path ../components npm run dev
```

Publishing to a topic:

```bash
dapr publish --publish-app-id order --pubsub order-pub-sub --topic orders --data '{"orderId": "100"}'
```

Here is the console output where the payload is empty. The endpoint is triggered, but no payload.

```
== APP == Server started on port 3100
== APP == Data received: {}
```

My `pubsub.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: order-pub-sub
spec:
  type: pubsub.rabbitmq
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: host
      value: "amqp://localhost:5672"
    - name: durable
      value: "false"
    - name: deletedWhenUnused
      value: "false"
    - name: autoAck
      value: "false"
    - name: reconnectWait
      value: "0"
    - name: concurrency
      value: parallel
scopes:
  - order
  - delivery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that I should expect a [CloudEvents](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/pubsub-cloudevents/) payload with my configuration.

Modifying my code to use the appropriate body parser solved the issue:

```js
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
```

It would also be possible to use [raw data](https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/pubsub/pubsub-raw/), but for my case I'll keep as it is.